# Align math equations left in Github markdown/mathjax

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

How can I align math equations to the left in Github markdown syntax? My attempt using "align" doesn't work. My equations are always centered horizontally.

```
$$
\begin{align}
sin⁡(α)={opposite \over hypotenuse}={h0 \over c}={h2 \over b}
\end{align}
$$
```

EDIT: Issue posted to GitHub at https://github.com/github/markup/issues/1570

Answer (score 2):

The [Math support in Markdown](https://github.blog/2022-05-19-math-support-in-markdown/) is fairly recent (May 2022) and the [block expression syntax `$$`](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/writing-mathematical-expressions#writing-expressions-as-blocks=) seems to *always* render a centered result.

You might need to consider an [inline expression syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/writing-mathematical-expressions#writing-inline-expressions=) instead.

```
$\sqrt{3x-1}+(1+x)^2$     <=== # two trailing whitespace
$\sqrt{3x-1}+(1+x)^2$
```

For a bigger size, using as a workaround the title header `##`:

```
## $\sqrt{3x-1}+(1+x)^2$     <=== # two trailing whitespace
## $\sqrt{3x-1}+(1+x)^2$
```

Comment: It worked, but the equations appear very small as a result of having to fit inline.

Comment: @sw1337 That is unfortunate. Would it be a bit bigger if you precede your inline expression with `##`? That is `## $\sqrt{3x-1}+(1+x)^2$`

Comment: That actually did the trick, at the expense of having a line under the equation (from the heading style) and the various members of the equation are a different font size because it's still trying to fit within a line. Not ideal but that will do. I would actually submit an issue to GitHub if I could figure out which of their 400+ repos this feature is sitting in...

Comment: @sw1337 OK. Can you comment here to communicate the link to that issue? I have edited the answer to include the `##` header workaround.

Comment: OK I posted a new issue at https://github.com/github/markup/issues/1570

Comment: @sw1337 Thank you. I will monitor it, and update this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

By referring the raw data of the example shown in [link](https://gist.github.com/Piyush3dB/1ebf1812671e2ab65695), You can see that both of the following work:

```
$$
\begin{align}
\mbox{Union: } & A\cup B = \{x\mid x\in A \mbox{ or } x\in B\} \\
\mbox{Concatenation: } & A\circ B  = \{xy\mid x\in A \mbox{ and } y\in B\} \\
\mbox{Star: } & A^\star  = \{x_1x_2\ldots x_k \mid  k\geq 0 \mbox{ and each } x_i\in A\} \\
\end{align}
$$
```

and

```
$$
\begin{align*} 
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{align*}
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also interested in this question, so I studied the description of different types of "environments" in these documents:

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics
- https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/amsldoc.pdf
- https://katex.org/docs/supported.html
- https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf

and experimented with what is written there using GitHub.
I see no reason to waste time on a detailed description, in short, part of the described "environments" gives the error "KaTeX parse error: No such environment", part aligns math equations in the middle. As a result, I found the only option that aligns on the left:

```
    $
    \begin{aligned}
    &sin⁡(α) = {opposite \over hypotenuse} = {h0 \over c} = {h2 \over b} \\
    &cos(α) = {adjacent \over hypotenuse} = {b \over c} = {d \over b} \\
    &tan⁡(α) = {opposite \over adjacent} = {h0 \over b} = {h2 \over d}
    \end{aligned}
    $
```